# Problem converting C# delegate & event code to VB

Tags: c#, vb.net

First off, I am not a C# programmer, nor am I a professional coder at all, but I'm far more familiar with VB than with C#.

I am working on converting some C# code to VB. I'm having issues with a few lines to do with delegates & events in two classes. The following is the working C# code:

```
using System;

namespace Controllers
{
    internal delegate T2 genDelegate<T1, T2>(T1 param);
    internal delegate T3 genDelegate<T1, T2, T3>(ref T1 param1, ref T2 param2);
}
```

and

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace Controllers
{
    internal static class wInt
    {
        internal static event genDelegate<Boolean, Boolean> noAllow;
        internal static event genDelegate<String, String, Boolean> connect;

        //some other stuff here

    }
}
```

And here is corresponding VB code that I've come up with so far...

```
Imports System

Namespace Controllers

  Friend Delegate Function genDelegate(Of T1, T2)(ByRef param As T1) As T2
  Friend Delegate Function genDelegate(Of T1, T2, T3)(ByRef param1 As T1, ByRef param2 As T2) As T3

End Namespace
```

and

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports System.Text

Namespace Controllers

  Public Class wIntVB

    Friend Shared Event noAllow As genDelegate(Of Boolean, Boolean)
    Friend Shared Event connect As genDelegate(Of String, String, Boolean)

  'some other stuff here'

  End Class
End Namespace
```

In the VB code, the two lines that start `Friend Shared Event` both give me this error:

> Events cannot be declared with a delegate type that has a return type.

I don't know if I've got the delegates set up correctly to begin with, so I don't know really where I'm going wrong on this.

Comment: Mistranslation, not related to the error: in the first delegate, `(T1 param)` should become `(ByVal param As T1)` in VB. When a C# parameter doesn't have `out`, `ref`, or `in`, it's passed by value, which translates to `ByVal`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert C# to VB,NET: Event with a delegate type that has a return type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43174571/convert-c-sharp-to-vb-net-event-with-a-delegate-type-that-has-a-return-type)

Comment: You have two options. Don't make your event have a return type. Or don't translate the c# to vb.net and keep it in a separate c# project within your solution. The latter is best to keep the same functionality.